# Read only $resource in Angular JS

Tags: angularjs

I'm using ngResource to retrieve data from the server. Most of this data supports normal CRUD operations. There's some data though (like report data) that doesn't support create, update or delete. It should only be read.

So is it bad form to still use code like this when retrieving data from the server? I know that the save, update and delete functions on the returned object will fail.

```
.factory('ReportData', function ($resource) {
    return $resource(baseURL + 'reportData');
})
```

The alternative would be using $http I guess? If so, I'd manually have to write a lot of the nice functionality that $resource gets me for free.

Comment: You can create custom resource objects with specified crud operations (in your case, only `GET`). Use the third argument in `$resource` to specify custom methods on your factory.

Comment: why not just use `$http` for routes that don't support full crud?

Comment: @Daniel_L: If I used something like: `{
            query: {
                method: 'GET',
                isArray: true
            }
        }`

then the returned object still has all of the normal $save, $delete, etc methods on it.

Comment: @Derek are you leaving the first two arguments blank? IIRC it should look like `$resource( "", {}, /** custom methods as object literal */ )`